# How do I set a command block outside the worldborder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing in Captive Minecraft by Farlander, but there's been a mishap and I need to edit a command block outside the worldborder. I can teleport out well enough, but I need to be able edit the command blocks.

Is there a way to interact with commandblocks outside the worldborder without actually expanding it? I'm afraid that the game might break if I expand it.

Comment: If you're afraid of breaking it, you can also make a backup of the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend opening the world in [McEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/), it should allow you to select the command block and edit its data.

You may also be able to edit it using /blockdata, but that may be a bit hard if you don't know the exact location of the command block